# How to test my android app in multiple versions of android

Tags: android, cordova

I built an android app using phonegap.

The app is working fine in kitkat 4.4.4 and Lollipop 5.0.

But I am facing some issues in Jelly bean 4.3.

I have an .apk file, now I want to test the app in multiple versions of android.

I searched for some web sites, those are asking for a Credit Card (I dont have one).

I need a better solution to test the app.

Comment: If you have the apk, you can try out Genymotion Emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have android 4.3 device then do this,

Copy your apk file in to device and  Navigate to the directory where you have copied or downloaded your APK file. Mostly, it’s stored in the “Downloads” folder on your Android device. Once in the directory, tap the APK icon and an installation dialogue box will pop-up. Hit the install button to install the APK on your Android.

you can also try this,
Download genymotion(Genymotion is a fast and easy-to-use Android emulator to run and test your Android apps) and install your apk to any device.

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

Comment: Genymotion is good option ,but it need to download OS vesrions. I thought there would be some free webservice